# My shell has to interpret the double quote

Tags: shell, double-quotes

I have to write a shell that can interpret double quotes.
I've written a basic shell.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
  int main ()
  {
    int i;
char * ligne;
char *tokens[100];
ligne=(char*)malloc(300);
printf("$ ");
fgets(ligne,256,stdin);
while (strcmp(ligne,"exit\n"))
{   i=0;
    tokens[i]=strtok(ligne," \n");
    while (tokens[i] != NULL) tokens[++i]=strtok(NULL," \n");
    if (fork()==0)
    {   execvp(tokens[0],tokens);
        printf("Commande invalide\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    wait(0);
    printf("$ ");
    fgets(ligne,256,stdin);
}
exit(0);
}
```

In a linux shell: When you enter a command like

```
 $ echo "`a     b`"
```

The shell interprets spaces and therefore

```
a     b
```

is taken as a file.

I do not see how to remove the double quotes and keep the spaces.
Thank you.

Comment: `Use single quotes to retain the space`. And please make your question more clear(as what output are you expecting) so I can provide the exact answer you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`strtok`is not suited for that. Replace

```
    tokens[i]=strtok(ligne," \n");
    while (tokens[i] != NULL) tokens[++i]=strtok(NULL," \n");
```

e. g. with

```
    char quot = 0, *cp;
    for (cp = ligne; tokens[i] = cp += strspn(cp, " \n"), *cp; ++i)
    {
        do if (*cp == '"') quot ^= 1, memmove(cp, cp+1, strlen(cp));
         while (cp += strcspn(cp, quot ? "\"" : " \n\""), *cp == '\"');
        if (*cp) *cp++ = '\0';
    }
    tokens[i] = NULL;
    if (quot) puts("unmatched quotation mark");
    else
```

.